# Do onclick listeners or inline html links take over if both are present?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, event-handling

Desired functionality: If x is true, open a modal. If x is false, link to an external url.

I have an image wrapped in a link tag -

```
<a href="http://google.com"><img src="htp://jkjfkd.com"></img></a>
```

Which also has an on click listener

```
onClickImg: function(e) {
   //Opens a modal if x is true
}
```

Testing this, it seems that the click is always "captured" by the on-click listener and the link is never called, even if x is false. My intuition, however would be that the link would always override the on-click listener. I haven't been able to find any information about which will override which or why. Can anyone explain why I am getting the functionality I am on a fundamental level, or tell me if the link should be overriding the listener and I am testing wrong?

I also understand that I could link in the on click function instead, but would like to do it in the template.

Comment: If you're not calling e.preventDefault() inside of an event listener for the link, the page should still redirect to the URL provided in the href of your link.

Comment: i would capture the click on the link instead of the image, but if you impliment the default link behavior, you can do it from the img as well